# CUDA: does size of input/output data have to be a multiple of the number of threads per block?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cuda, raytracing, pycuda

I have a Python code (for implementing RayTracing) that I'm running in parallel with PyCuda.

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
import time
my_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('test_solid_py.stl')
n = my_mesh.normals
v0 = my_mesh.v0
v1 = my_mesh.v1
v2 = my_mesh.v2
v0_x = v0[:,0]
v0_x = np.ascontiguousarray(v0_x)
v0_y = v0[:,1]
v0_y = np.ascontiguousarray(v0_y)
v0_z = v0[:,2]
v0_z = np.ascontiguousarray(v0_z)
v1_x = v1[:,0]
v1_x = np.ascontiguousarray(v1_x)
v1_y = v1[:,1]
v1_y = np.ascontiguousarray(v1_y)
v1_z = v1[:,2]
v1_z = np.ascontiguousarray(v1_z)
v2_x = v2[:,0]
v2_x = np.ascontiguousarray(v2_x)
v2_y = v2[:,1]
v2_y = np.ascontiguousarray(v2_y)
v2_z = v2[:,2]
v2_z = np.ascontiguousarray(v2_z)

mod = SourceModule("""
    #include <math.h>
  __global__ void intersect(float *origin,float *dir_x,float *dir_y,float *dir_z,float *v0_x,float *v0_y,float *v0_z,float *v1_x,float *v1_y,float *v1_z,float *v2_x,float *v2_y,float *v2_z,float *int_point_real_x, float *int_point_real_y,float *int_point_real_z)
  {
    using namespace std;
    unsigned int idx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int count = 0;

    float v0_current[3];
    float v1_current[3];
    float v2_current[3];
    float dir_current[3] = {dir_x[idx],dir_y[idx],dir_z[idx]}; 
    float int_point[3];
    float int_pointS[2][3];
    int int_faces[2];
    float dist[2];
    dist[0] = -999;
    int n_tri = 105500;

    for(int i = 0; i<n_tri; i++) {
        v0_current[0] = v0_x[i];
        v0_current[1] = v0_y[i];
        v0_current[2] = v0_z[i];
        v1_current[0] = v1_x[i];
        v1_current[1] = v1_y[i];
        v1_current[2] = v1_z[i];
        v2_current[0] = v2_x[i];
        v2_current[1] = v2_y[i];
        v2_current[2] = v2_z[i];
        double eps = 0.0000001;
        float E1[3];
        float E2[3];
        float s[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            E1[j] = v1_current[j] - v0_current[j];
            E2[j] = v2_current[j] - v0_current[j];
            s[j] = origin[j] - v0_current[j];
        }
        float h[3];
        h[0] = dir_current[1] * E2[2] - dir_current[2] * E2[1];
        h[1] = -(dir_current[0] * E2[2] - dir_current[2] * E2[0]);
        h[2] = dir_current[0] * E2[1] - dir_current[1] * E2[0];
        float a;
        a = E1[0] * h[0] + E1[1] * h[1] + E1[2] * h[2];
        if (a > -eps && a < eps) {
            int_point[0] = false;
        }
        else {
            double f = 1 / a;
            float u;
            u = f * (s[0] * h[0] + s[1] * h[1] + s[2] * h[2]);
            if (u < 0 || u > 1) {
                int_point[0] = false;
            }
            else {
                float q[3];
                q[0] = s[1] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[1];
                q[1] = -(s[0] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[0]);
                q[2] = s[0] * E1[1] - s[1] * E1[0];
                float v;
                v = f * (dir_current[0] * q[0] + dir_current[1] * q[1] + dir_current[2] * q[2]);
                if (v < 0 || (u + v)>1) {
                    int_point[0] = false;
                }
                else {
                    float t;
                    t = f * (E2[0] * q[0] + E2[1] * q[1] + E2[2] * q[2]);
                    if (t > eps) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            int_point[j] = origin[j] + dir_current[j] * t;
                        }
                        //return t;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (int_point[0] != false) {
            count = count+1;
            int_faces[count-1] = i;
            dist[count-1] = sqrt(pow((origin[0] - int_point[0]), 2) + pow((origin[1] - int_point[1]), 2) + pow((origin[2] - int_point[2]), 2));
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
                int_pointS[count-1][j] = int_point[j];
            }
        }
    }
    double min = dist[0];
    int ind_min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (min > dist[i]) {
            min = dist[i];
            ind_min = i;
        }
    }
    if (dist[0] < -998){
        int_point_real_x[idx] = -999;
        int_point_real_y[idx] = -999;
        int_point_real_z[idx] = -999;
    }
    else{
        int_point_real_x[idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][0];
        int_point_real_y[idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][1];
        int_point_real_z[idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][2];
    }

}
  """)
n_rays = 20000
num_threads = 1024
num_blocks = int(n_rays/num_threads)
origin = np.asarray([-2, -2, -2]).astype(np.float32)
origin = np.ascontiguousarray(origin)
rand_x = np.random.randn(n_rays)
rand_y = np.random.randn(n_rays)
rand_z = np.random.randn(n_rays)
direction_x = np.ones((n_rays, 1)) * 3
direction_x = direction_x.astype(np.float32)
direction_x = np.ascontiguousarray(direction_x)
direction_y = np.ones((n_rays, 1)) * 4
direction_y = direction_y.astype(np.float32)
direction_y = np.ascontiguousarray(direction_y)
direction_z = np.ones((n_rays, 1)) * 5
direction_z = direction_z.astype(np.float32)
direction_z = np.ascontiguousarray(direction_z)
int_point_real_x = np.zeros((n_rays, 1)).astype(np.float32)
int_point_real_x = np.ascontiguousarray(int_point_real_x)
int_point_real_y = np.zeros((n_rays, 1)).astype(np.float32)
int_point_real_y = np.ascontiguousarray(int_point_real_y)
int_point_real_z = np.zeros((n_rays, 1)).astype(np.float32)
int_point_real_z = np.ascontiguousarray(int_point_real_z)

intersect = mod.get_function("intersect")
start = time.time()
intersect(drv.In(origin), drv.In(direction_x),drv.In(direction_y),drv.In(direction_z),drv.In(v0_x),drv.In(v0_y),drv.In(v0_z), drv.In(v1_x),drv.In(v1_y),drv.In(v1_z), drv.In(v2_x), drv.In(v2_y), drv.In(v2_z), drv.Out(int_point_real_x),drv.Out(int_point_real_y),drv.Out(int_point_real_z), block=(num_threads, 1, 1), grid=((num_blocks+0), 1, 1))
finish = time.time()
print(finish-start)
```

I give as input some arrays whose size is 20k (`dir_x`, `dir_y`, `dir_z`) and I have as output 3 arrays (`int_point_real_x`,`int_point_real_y`,`int_point_real_z`) that have the same size as the above mentioned arrays (20k).

If `n_rays` is a multiple of `num_threads`, e.g. `n_rays=19456` and `num_threads=1024`, then `int_point_real_x_y_z` are correctly filled by the kernel.

Otherwise, if `n_rays` is NOT a multiple of `num_threads`, e.g. `n_rays=20000` (what I really need) and `num_threads=1024`, then `int_point_real_x_y_z` are filled by the kernel up to position 19455 and the 544 spots left in the array are not filled.

Does anyone know if this is a rule of CUDA? 
If it's not, how could I modify my code in order to use an arbitrary size of input array (and not only multiple of `num_threads`)?

Thanks

Comment: Fully one third of the kernel code you have posted is commented out and does nothing. I am not sure what your interpretation on an [MCVE] is, but mine wouldn't include a kernel with 30+ lines of irrelevant commented out code in it

Comment: I edited the question and removed all the commented lines. If you need the 'test_solid_py.stl' file I can provide it in some way

Answer (score 1):

your `int(n_rays/num_threads)` is rounding down

to fix this, you need to round up and then put a condition into the kernel to enforce that `idx` is valid and "do nothing" if it's not.  this will cause some cores to waste time, but your code looks pretty suboptimal anyway so it probably won't matter much

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with "enforce that idx is valid"?

Comment: here's an example, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217294/should-i-check-the-number-of-threads-in-kernel-code/26217725#26217725)